# DBSCAN Clustering in Weka 3-8-1

Tags: java, command-line, cluster-analysis, weka, dbscan

After installing the OPTICS_DBSCAN package in Weka from the GUI, using the Weka Package Manager, I am able to run the algorithm using the GUI. But when using the commandline interface, it throws an error saying the following.

`Error: Could not find or load main class weka.clusterers.DBSCAN`

I have copied the command from the GUI itself and do not understand what the error could be. The following is the command.

`java weka.clusterers.DBSCAN -E 0.9 -M 6 -A "weka.core.EuclideanDistance -R first-last" -t "ARFF_Files/Jain.arff"`

Any ideas what the problem could be?

PS: I have tried both DBSCAN and DBScan as the name, as I saw two variants floating around on the net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct spelling of DBSCAN is all uppercase, but the Weka class was for a long time named differently.

You need to add the `.jar` to your classpath. Weka has introduced this extension system, but the command line will *not* automatically load extensions you installed in the GUI. You need to setup the Java classpath yourself.

Please use [ELKI](https://elki-project.github.io/) instead of Weka. You will notice that it is a *lot* faster, in particular when you enable data indexes. Also, ELKI has many more clustering algorithms, and a complete OPTICS. Weka's OPTICS does not have the Xi extraction if I recall correctly. In our experiments, **Weka was one of the slowest implementations benchmarked** (the only slower implementation was R's `fpc` package):

> Kriegel, H. P., Schubert, E., & Zimek, A. (2017).
> **[The (black) art of runtime evaluation: Are we comparing algorithms or implementations?](http://rdcu.be/uHkO)**
>  Knowledge and Information Systems, 52(2), 341-378.

The fastest tools would cluster the data in 1.5 (low-level optimized C++) to 7 seconds (Java), with indexes. Weka took over 1100 seconds. That is over 100x slower on this data set.